# JS Callback on writing html to element

Tags: javascript, html, callback

I have a short script which writes into the documnet.getElement(xxx).innerHTML = myGeneratedHTML.

I also have a jquery piece of code for writing a styling over the generated HTML.
The issue is, I need the jquery method to run after the writing of HTML to the document.

I need to do a callback, but the callbacks I have seen were for extracting data from files and url's, is there a callback which waits till the html is finished writing to the document?

Comment: it should be synchronous.

Comment: You can much better add an `id` attribute to the HTML element you are adding, and then specify the content-specific styles in CSS. You could also add an extra class to the element returned by `document.getElement(xxx)` to indicate you've added the dynamically loaded content. Perhaps normally `<div class="container">` , and when filled `<div class="container filled">`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is such a call back, after writing elements to the DOM you should be able to access them immediately - I would simply update the styling etc after you have run the function to update the HTML.

Better yet, keep all you syntax in jQuery - your using the library already so why not make life easier for yourself and use its functions to do what you need?  So update the HTML using jQuery and the styling using jQuery in this order and you should find no problems.

ie -

```
$('#wantedElement').html("This is some html");
$('#wantedElement').css("color", "red");
```

Are you wanting to style the newly generated elements within the html? Can you supply some example code (ie what is the html within `myGeneratedHTML`)?  Then you would do something like this:

```
$('#wantedElement').html("<div class='anotherElement'>This is some html</div>");
$('#wantedElement .anotherElement').css("color", "red");
```

You really shouldn't have to wait for it to be written if using jQuery and you certainly shouldn't need to set up a loop or use `setInterval` to check for this.

To add to the question in the comments about adding styling to HTML coming from a JSON callback.

So replace this:

```
documnet.getElement(xxx).innerHTML = myGeneratedHTML
```

With this:

```
$('#someElement').html(connHTML);
```

And immediately after the above you can start styling it so in full the above should be replaced with:

```
//add the generated html from JSON call - where 'connHTML'
//is a variable containing the generated HTML from the JSON
//call and it contains a table

$('#someElement').html(connHTML);

//now style the content
$('#someElement table').css("width","100%");
$('#someElement table').css("background-color","red");
$('#someElement table').css("color","white");
```

The above code could be simplified but is written like this for readability ;)

Comment: The HTML generated by the JS is a table: `code: var connHTML =  '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="heat-map"><thead><tr><th class="first">First header</th>... </table> ` . This code is run after a json callback which extracts the info for the table. It's three steps which loads a JSON first, then using a callback it inserts the data to a table, the last part is applying the styling

Comment: I appreciate the simplicity of your solution. However, my table was already apart of a callback and the styling is not a small piece of code either, so I'm not sure how it would have been applied for me. Do you have a link where I can study an example?

Comment: Thanks John, the thing is you really shouldn't be running a loop to test whether it is written to the page, this to me is definitely bad practice, you should be running the above code on a call back from the JSON query (which is when you write the html to the page) - you can even do `$('#someElement').html(connHTML);` directly after this line you can start adding styling - see updated answer (in 1 sec ;) )

Comment: Thank you for this further comment, it has helped me to get it to work. I can't believe how clean that is, big thank acSlater!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an interval to check if the HTML of the element matches your HTML:

```
var intervalCounter = setInterval(function() {
  if(documnet.getElement(xxx).innerHTML == myGeneratedHTML) {
    alert("HTML Loaded");
    clearInterval(intervalCounter);
    intervalCounter = null;
  }
}, 10);

documnet.getElement(xxx).innerHTML = myGeneratedHTML;
```

Comment: when I try this it doesn't load, I get an uncaught reference error at the if statement, which looks like   if(documnet.getElementById("connectionsdata").innerHTML == connHTML)

Comment: You have a typo: documnet instead of document

Comment: DAMN YOU GREYSKULL!!!!! Always a typo where you don't expect it. Thank you Blade0rz, it works!

Comment: I believe this is bad practice - you should not need to run `setInterval` to see if your own script has written HTML to the page

Comment: Although it might be considered bad practise, it has helped me to understand these calls for the future.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem, so I went ahead and wrote a plugin for it.

```
$(selector).waitExists(function);
```

and code:

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.waitExists    = function (handler, shouldRunHandlerOnce, isChild) {
    var found       = 'found';
    var $this       = $(this.selector);
    var $elements   = $this.not(function () { return $(this).data(found); }).each(handler).data(found, true);

    if (!isChild)
    {
        (window.waitExists_Intervals = window.waitExists_Intervals || {})[this.selector] =
            window.setInterval(function () { $this.waitExists(handler, shouldRunHandlerOnce, true); }, 500)
        ;
    }
    else if (shouldRunHandlerOnce && $elements.length)
    {
        window.clearInterval(window.waitExists_Intervals[this.selector]);
    }

    return $this;
}

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: or a simple way: [jquery.livequery.js](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery/blob/master/jquery.livequery.js)